# Stack Overflow Error while using JPanel.setLocation with an StretchIcon (ImageIcon) in it

Tags: java, swing

Trying to make a movable object with JPanel, which has a ImageIcon which will automaticly stretch when I resize it.
Now, when I run the application, it activates properly and shows the image.
However when I press a button it shows the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.awt.Component.setLocation(Unknown Source)
    at tutorial.GridPanel.move(GridPanel.java:51)
    at java.awt.Component.setLocation(Unknown Source)
    at tutorial.GridPanel.move(GridPanel.java:51)
    at java.awt.Component.setLocation(Unknown Source)
    at tutorial.GridPanel.move(GridPanel.java:51)
    (continue many times)
```

Found that it is maybe a king of indirect recursion? thing, but I just cannot find what is causing it. Following is the class GridPanel I wrote for the JPanel.

```java
package tutorial;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import darrylbu.icon.StretchIcon;

public class GridPanel extends JPanel
{   
    private BufferedImage image;

    GridPanel() {}
    GridPanel(String path)
    {
        setLayout(null);
        try
        {
            image = ImageIO.read(new File(path));
        }catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter()
        {
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
            {
                System.out.println(e.getKeyChar());
                move(10, 10);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        StretchIcon icon = new StretchIcon(image);            
        icon.paintIcon(this, g, 0, 0);
    }

    public void move(int x, int y)
    {
        super.setLocation(getX() + x, getY() + y);
    }
}
```

Comment: `setLocation` calls `move`, which is calling you `move` again, because you've overridden it ... on a side note. I'd avoid doing this this way.  To start with, there's no need to create a new `StretchIcon` every time `paintComponent` is called.  You could also re-position the instance of `icon` within the panel, based on the location your prefer, rather the trying to change the location of the panel itself, which could have a number of undesirable side effects

Comment: @MadProgrammer  Never found that I am overriding the `move` method. Thanks alot. About the `StretchIcon` thing, so does it mean that I should declair something like `private StretchIcon s` in the class?

Comment: That would be a good start.  The real answer, however, would depend greatly on what it is you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
public void setLocation(int x, int y)
{
  move (x, y);
}
```

That is the source code for [Component](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/awt/Component-source.html).setLocation(). As you can see: that method calls `move()`. You panel overrides `move()` to call `setLocation()`. There we go: your recursion is not "indirect", it is right there.

So obviously: do not call `setLocation()` from your `move()` method! So your whole approach is flawed at this point.

Comment: Thank you for telling me that I am overriding the `move` function. Never found that and it solved everything LOL.